# asynchronously plot data with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, python-multithreading, pyqtgraph

I have a simulation code and I would like to add diagnostic plotting to it with pyqtgraph.

The simulation is implemented in a Python class. In pseudo-code,

```
class Simulation:
    [...]
    '''
    Defines self.data, the stuff that needs plotting
    and self.done, which is False and becomese True once the simulation
    is over.
    '''

    def evolve(self):
        ''' takes care of updating self.data'''
        [...]
        self.done = True

    def get_data(self):
         return self.data
```

and I would like to keep it independent from the plotting infrastructure.

What I'm trying to do is to create a plotting class, which so far I tried to implement with python threading, that reads

```
import pyqtgraph as pg                                                         
import threading                                                               
from time import sleep                                                         
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui

class Plot(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, source, target_fps=10):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.source = source
        self.wait_time = 1. / target_fps

        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
        self.plot = self.win.addPlot()
        self.curve = self.plot.plot()
        self.curve.setData(self.source.get_data())

    def run(self):
        while not self.source.done:
            self.curve.setData(self.source.get_data())
            sleep(self.wait_time)
```

whose job is to poll the source class once in a while and update the plot. Then my `__main__` would be something along the lines of

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sim = Simulation() # initialise simulation code
    plotter = Plot(sim)  # <- By commenting these three lines
    plotter.start()      # <- I fall back to a working simulation
    sim.evolve()         #
    plotter.join()       # <- without plotting diagnostics
```

Of course the previous `__main__` doesn't work because it is missing the Qt event loop required by `pyqtgraph`, something of the like of `pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()`, which carries the inconvenient side effect of blocking the execution of the rest of the code after it. If I try to put the `exec_()` inside `Plot.run()` I get a warning that the event loop must be run from within the main thread, and plots don't show up.

Is there a workaround that I can use to make the plotting class work and not block the execution of the simulation? I would like not to touch the `Simulation` class.

Comment: you just call once to evolve?

Comment: evolve will typically contain a loop that takes care of time evolution, and more generally it is a collection of many different steps (evolution, measurement, etc), all affecting the data to plot

Comment: You can use pydispatch to communicate between threads. This would mean running the simulation class in a thread from the pyqtgraph class. Then use dispatches to send the data from the simulation to the plotting class. This would mean changing your simulation class though, to add dispatch event handlers.

Comment: @japs If you could model better your example could help you, in your code I only see that it only processes the data once, so I see the threads unnecessary, or the processing is continuous, if so, improve your example?

Comment: Is the simulation class thread safe? Would it be OK if it existed in a separate thread if that can be done without modifying the class? I ask because At is **not** thread safe, so calling `setData` from a thread like your example does is likely to lead to segfaults. A better approach would be to instantiate the simulation class inside a `QThread` and periodically emit a Qt signal back to the main thread containing the new data to be put in the plot.